# Find the limit of a multivariable function that's a quotient of polynomials: $f(x)=\frac{x^3y^3}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

The functions is as follows:

$f(x)=\frac{x^3y^3}{x^2+y^2}$

Now, the limit at $(0,0)$ does exist and it's $0$ but I only know that from WolframAlpha. I've tried all fractional manipulations I can think of but I can't get that $0$ out of the denominator. I'm assuming that this has to be solved by the definition. If so, would someone be so kind to show me how?

From what I understand, I need to prove that

$\frac{x^3y^3}{x^2+y^2}<\epsilon$

using only the assumption that

$\|(x,y)\|<\delta$

where $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$. How do I do that (if it's even correct)?

Comment: Try changing it into polar coordinates and take $r\to 0$ and show that it approaches to $0$ from all directions.

Comment: That's not enough.

Comment: Why isn't that enough?

Comment: You can have a function that converges to the same value from all linear directions but doesn't if you take a parabola as a path for example. I need to prove that the limit I get is the actual limit.

Comment: If the bound works *uniformly* for all directions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(x,y)=\frac{x^3y^3}{x^2+y^2}={r^6\cos^3\theta\sin^3\theta\over r^2}=r^4\cos^3\theta\sin^3\theta
$$

$$
|f(x,y)|\le r^4 = (x^2+y^2)^2
$$
Where is the problem?

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. Do you think that's proof enough that 0 is in fact the limit?

Comment: Squeeze theorem or a easy $\epsilon$-$\delta$ reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac{x^3y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le|xy^3|\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to (0,0)]{}0$$

Comment: That's pretty great. Can I ask you where you got the $xy^3$ from?

Comment: @Darwin :$$\frac1{x^2+y^2}\le\frac1{x^2}$$